# Passing parameter to <ice:rowSelector>'s clickListener attribute

Tags: icefaces, clicklistener

I'm trying to use the IceFaces (+ Seam 3 Framework on Jboss AS7) "ice:rowSelector" tag in a way that when a dataTable's row is cliked, the data in that row will be show in a "ice:panelGrid" tag with "ice:outputLabel"s.

I'm setting the clickListener as in some examples around, like this:

```
<ice:rowSelector immediate="true" clickListener="#{categoryController.selectionListener}"/>
```

the method is:

```
public void selectionListener(ClickActionEvent clickActionEvent) {

    selectedCategory= categories.get(clickActionEvent.getRow());
}
```

being "categories"

```
List<Category> categories
```

But when I test the app, I get a javax.el.MethodNotFoundException exception. Then I add the "()"s to the method call (clickListener="#{categoryController.selectionListener()}"), getting the same exception.

Finally, I set clickListener="#{categoryController.selectionListener(clickActionEvent)}" and the method is called BUT "clickActionEvent" makes it throw NullPointException. The relevant part is:

```
    Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /showCategory.xhtml @20,114 clickListener="#{categoryController.selectionListener(clickActionEvent)}": java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
        at com.icesoft.faces.component.facelets.MethodExpressionMethodBinding.invoke(IceComponentHandler.java:231) [icefaces-compat-3.0.1.jar:]
        at com.icesoft.faces.component.ext.RowSelector.broadcast(RowSelector.java:530) [icefaces-compat-3.0.1.jar:]
        at org.icefaces.impl.component.UISeriesBase.broadcast(UISeriesBase.java:481) [icefaces-3.0.1.jar:]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:935) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
        ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My question is: what should I pass as ClickActionEvent parameter to the "selectionListener" method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what should I pass as ClickActionEvent parameter to the
>   "selectionListener" method?

Pass [RowSelectorEvent](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v1_8_2/javadocs/components/api/com/icesoft/faces/component/ext/RowSelectorEvent.html).

Comment: Like in clickListener="#categoryController.selectionListener(rowSelectorEvent)}"  ?

It returns me NullPointerException just like with clickActionEvent.
?

Comment: No, in backing bean you define RowSelectorEvent as parameter type. And instead of clickListener try `selectionListener="#{categoryController.selectionListener}"`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Allright, changing the method parameter from ClickActionEvent to RowSelectorEvent and calling it with selectionListener="#{categoryController.rowSelectionListener}" did the trick.

Although my NetBeans IDE "complains" that categoryController.rowSelectionListener is an unknown property.

If possible I'd like to know how to satisfy the IDE and whats the difference between click and selector listeners.

Thank you very much!

Comment: @kauedg I think NB does not see methods with parameters. I mean listener method takes a parameter, and in EL we do not specify any. Maybe they will fix this in further versions.